# Hutchinson's Latin translation of Xenophon's Anabasis

Tags: resource-request

Does anyone know where I could find a complete version of Hutchinson's Latin translation of Xenophon's Anabasis?

A partial version is linked below.  (The box at the top lists the available sections.)

http://www.gottwein.de/Grie/xenophon/anab1_01.php

Internet resources would be best, but information on hard copy (publisher, year of publication, etc.) would also be appreciated.

I don't know that a complete version exists.  It is possible that the link above links all that has been translated.  Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Here you go.](https://archive.org/stream/xenophntoskyrou02hutcgoog#page/n6/mode/2up) Internet Archive is a treasury full of old gems.

They [also have](https://archive.org/search.php?query=creator%3A%22Xenophon%2C%20Thomas%20Hutchinson%22) several versions of the *Cyropedia*, too, if you're interested.

Comment: Thank you--particularly as I even looked in Internet Archive and couldn't find it.

Comment: @Catomic My pleasure. Sometimes one just needs a second pair of eyes—it happens!